# Which symbol should I use to indicate "transpose"?

Tags: notation, transposition

I'm making an online chord database, and I want symbols instead of words to label everything, so it can be used by non English speakers. E.g. instead of "Home" I have a picture of a house.

I have a feature to transpose chords up or down, and I'm just wondering if there's a standard symbol for "transpose"?

Comment: Are these guitar chords or piano chords or something else? I only ask because on a guitar you **can** sometimes slide a chord position up and down the neck, but you can't do that on a piano. And don't the note names change with the language too, e.g. Do vs C

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS they are written chords like "C   Am   F" etc, so applicable to piano and guitar. About the language, yea I know German swaps B for H, so it wont be perfect, but the aim is the least amount of english knowledge needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like ⬆️ and ⬇️ ? I just did this with emojis to demonstrate. I don’t know any standard symbols for transpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an existing symbol. How about some variation on the following?

[image]